# Facing problem with logout URL for ping identity provider

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, pingfederate

I am working on implementing Oauth2.0 using Ping Identity in my project. I am facing trouble while using the logout url. This is the url for logout
`https://x.com/idp/startSLO.ping?id_token_hint=${token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${AUTH_URL.logoutRedirectUri}&state=${state}`

Upon accessing this url for logout , I am getting the following error
"Sign Off Error
Logging off for all sites did not succeed. To complete the logoff process, we recommend that you close all of your browser windows."

And I am getting the following  error in console
"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 'my homepage url'  with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue?

I went through the Q&A on the ping identity site but I didn't find any helpful responses.